# Logical Equivalence Law for Removing Parentheses

Tags: math, logical-operators, operation

I have a problem problem such as:

> ¬P ∨ (Q ∨ R)

I used the law that :

> ¬P ∨ (Q ∨ R) ≡ ¬P ∨ Q ∨ R

But I do not remember the name of the law. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of the associative law, but there is a subtlety:

What the associative law says is that

```
P v (Q v R) = (P v Q) v R
```

Depending on your formal system of logic, there is a good chance that

```
P v Q v R
```

isn't officially a wff (*well-formed formula*) since it is syntactically ambiguous. The associative law guarantees that both ways of parsing it are equivalent, hence it is a common abbreviation for `(P v Q) v R`.

Thus, I would tend to regard

```
P v (Q v R) = P v Q v R
```

as giving an abbreviation which is underwritten by the associative law rather than as an *application* of the associative law per se.